# Solr NGram filtering not matching search term

Tags: solr

I have NGram filtering enabled for a keywords field I am indexing, which contains the following comma separated terms:

wwwdebenhams.com, ebenhams.com, dbenhams.com, deenhams.com, debnhams.com, debehams.com, debenams.com, debenhms.com, debenhas.com, debenham.com, debenhams.ocm, debenhams.con, debenhams.comn, debenhams.copm, debenhams.comm, debenhams.coom, debenhams.xom, debenhams.cpm, ebenhams.com, dbenhams.com, deenhams.com, debnhams.com, debehams.com, debenams.com, debenhms.com, debenhas.com, debenham.com,

The schema for the core looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<schema name="merchant" version="1.0">
    <types>
    <!--
          Default numeric field types. For faster range queries, consider the           tint/tfloat/tlong/tdouble types.
        -->
        <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0"     positionIncrementGap="0"/>

        <fieldType name="text_lowercase_ngram" class="solr.TextField"     termPositions="false" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer type="index">
               <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    splitOnCaseChange="0"
                    splitOnNumerics="0"
                    stemEnglishPossessive="0"
                    generateWordParts="1"
                    generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="0"
                    catenateNumbers="0"
                    catenateAll="0"
                    preserveOriginal="1"
                    types="wdfftypes.txt"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="20"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    splitOnCaseChange="0"
                    splitOnNumerics="0"
                    stemEnglishPossessive="0"
                    generateWordParts="1"
                    generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="0"
                    catenateNumbers="0"
                    catenateAll="0"
                    preserveOriginal="1"
                    types="wdfftypes.txt"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="20"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_exact" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
</types>

<fields>
    <!-- Merchant Fields -->
    <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="site_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="title" type="text_lowercase_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="url" type="text_exact" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="keywords" type="text_lowercase_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="description" type="text_lowercase_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="type" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="popularity" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="category" type="text_exact" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
</fields>

<!-- field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. -->
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

<!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
<defaultSearchField>title</defaultSearchField>

<!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

Searching 'deb' returns the matching document with a score of 6.4406505.  Searching 'debe', 'deben', 'debenh' and 'debenha' returns no results.  Searching 'debenham' returns the matching document with a score of 41.740173 and 'debenhams' returns the document with a score of 111.30711.

I have tried using the query analyzer which shows matching terms for each of the above queries, yet I am not seeing the matching document coming back in the results.  Is there a way I can return ALL documents with corresponding scores regardless of whether they are a positive match or not in order to better understand why they are not being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should remove the NGramFilterFactory at query time. You really don't need to make ngrams of the query, and that's what is probably messing up your results. Also, is it possible that you are only looking the first ten results? Solr uses a default `rows=10` parameter; you can increase it or switch page using the `start` parameter. have a look at the `numFound` returned with your query, which contains the total number of results, even if you don't see them all.

Comment: I have re-read the section on N-Gram filtering in the book Apache Solr 3 Enterprise Search which bears out your comment about applying N-Gram filtering at index time only. For the purposes of testing, I only have 1 document in my index and the rows parameter would not be relevant in this case.  The [explain other](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Why_doesn.27t_document_id:juggernaut_appear_in_the_top_10_results_for_my_query) parameter may be helpful in returning my document and checking the scoring for  each of the different query strings.

Comment: Answer was spot on. After removing the N-Gram query analyser, I am now getting results back for each of the sub-string queries as expected.